# Making Copy Constructor w/Linked Lists

Tags: c++, linked-list, copy-constructor

This portion of my current assignment has me completely stumped:

I am trying to build a LinkedList class that includes a copy constructor, which itself calls a static method (*makeCopy()). I cannot figure out how to make the makeCopy method work (all method headers were given to us in the assignment).

```
class ListNode
{
public:
    ListNode(double v, ListNode *p)
{
   value = v; 
   next = p;
}
private:    
   double value;
   ListNode *next;
   friend class LinkedList;    // LinkedList  has friend status 
};

// The linked list class itself
class LinkedList
{
public:
//Add number to Linked List
void add(double x)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = new ListNode(x, NULL);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        ListNode *nodePtr = head;
        head = new ListNode(x, nodePtr);
    }

}
LinkedList() { head = NULL; }

//Default destructor
~LinkedList()
{
    ListNode *nodePtr = head;
    while (nodePtr != NULL)
    {
        ListNode *garbage = nodePtr;
        nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        delete garbage;
    }
}

//Copy Constructor
LinkedList(LinkedList &);

//Copy function
static ListNode *makeCopy(ListNode *pList);

private:
   ListNode * head;    

};
```

Below is how I am trying to write the makeCopy function:

```
LinkedList::LinkedList(LinkedList &list)
{
    *makeCopy(list.head);
}

static ListNode *makeCopy(ListNode *pList)
{
   if(pList->value == NULL)
   {        
       return NULL;
   }
   else
   {
    ListNode *node = pList;

    while(node != NULL)
    {
        ListNode newOne = *node;
        node = node->next;
    }
}

return;
}
```

First off I continue to get the error "member ListNode::value is innaccesible." Second I'm very new to C++ and pretty sure I'm way off. If someone could help nudge me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated. Thx

This is my current iteration of the copy constructor and the makeCopy method. Unfortunately the ListNode constructor, along with all the method headers, are part of the assignment. We have to write the code for them. The error I'm getting now is this: both return statements say "Error: a constructor or destructor may not return a value." I'm completely lost on this one since this is just a return statement and I don't see either a constructor or destructor.

```
LinkedList::LinkedList(LinkedList &list)
{
    LinkedList *copy = new LinkedList();

    while(list.head != NULL)
    {
        ListNode node = *makeCopy(list.head);
        copy->add(node.value);
        list.head = head->next;
    }

    return *copy;
 }

 ListNode * LinkedList::makeCopy(ListNode *pList)
 {
    ListNode node = *pList;

    return *node;
 }
```

Comment: You've defined makeCopy as a non-member function, not a member function (method). That's why it doesn't have access to the private members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static ListNode *makeCopy(ListNode *pList)
```

should be

```
ListNode * LinkedList::makeCopy(ListNode *pList)
```

Your version defines a free function with internal linkeage, and not defines the member.

Comment: @Martin true, but if it's a free function you can't access the private members, rendering even your code `newNode->value = node->value;` invalid. But I agree there are greater isses, +1 for you.

Comment: Sorry - I deleted my comment.  I had totally missed the whole point of the question - that makeCopy couldn't see the fields of LinkedNode :).

Answer (score 1):

**<Edit 1>** You first need to get the linkage of your makeCopy right - See Luchian's answer for the explanation of that. **</Edit 1>**

Your first problem is that at the beginning of makeCopy, you're comparing `value` (a double), to NULL (zero, for all intents and purposes), and returning a null pointer if they match.

I suspect you're actually meaning to say, if `pList` itself is NULL, return NULL.

Secondly, you're never actually making a copy of anything in makeCopy.  Inside the while loop, you're creating a new node on the stack, but that will just get created/destroyed on each iteration of the loop.

You need to create a copy of each node, using something like

```
ListNode * newNode = new Node();
newNode->value = node->value;
newNode->next = ???;
```

Note the use of new to create a new element.

The thing you need to work out (and I suspect the real goal of the homework, so I won't spoon feed you here), is how you set that `->next` field.

If you know the lists are small, you might consider recursion.  That wouldn't be very scalable though.

Otherwise, you need to find a way of setting the next pointer *after* you've copied the next element (this is the better way of doing it).

**<Edit 2>**
makeCopy is also not returning anything.  It needs to return a pointer to the copy of the head node (which you'll need to remember).

Your LinkedList copy constructor is also not actually doing anything.  It calls makeCopy, dereferences the pointer returned, then throws it all away.  You'll want to do something like `head = makeCopy(list.head)`.  Or even better, if you've learnt about field initialisers, then use field initialisation instead.
**/<Edit 2>***

Comment: And I completely missed the obvious as Vaughn and Luchian have pointed out.  You'll still run into the problems I've mentioned once you get it compiling though.

Comment: The ListNode constructor "ListNode(double v, ListNode *p)" is part of the assignment. One that's giving me headaches..

Comment: That's fine.  Just create your new nodes with `ListNode * newNode = new Node(node->value, NULL);`, then set newNode->next as appropriate (since LinkedList is a friend of LinkedNode).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your assigment correctly "makeCopy" takes a pointer to linked list of nodes and must create copy of this linked list and return pointer to the first element, right?

Here is what I think needs to be done:

```
LinkedList::LinkedList(LinkedList &list)
    : head(makeCopy(list.head))
{
}

ListNode* LinkedList::makeCopy(ListNode *pList)
{
   if (!pList)
   {
       return 0;
   }

   ListNode* head = new ListNode(plist->value, 0);
   ListNode* back = head;
   plist = plist->next;

   while (pList)
   {
       ListNode* newNode = new ListNode(plist->value, 0);
       back->next = newNode;
       back = newNode;
       plist = plist->next;
   }

   return head;
}
```

Comment: I think it's best to focus on explaining the concepts and techniques when answering these homework questions, than on providing the actual solutions.  The askers get a lot more out of understanding the solution than getting the right solution.